Pass cookie to a fetch request on a different subdmain
Say I have a html page on mycooldomain.com. On that page I do login to login.mycooldomain.com using axios.
    const smartAxiosLogin = axios.create({
        timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
        baseURL: 'https://login.mycooldomain.com:4000/api',
        withCredentials: true,
    });
    const smartAxios = axios.create({
        timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
        baseURL: 'https://smartpmoapi.mycooldomain.com:4100/api',
        withCredentials: true,
    });
        $("#login_form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let email= $('#username_login').val();
            let password= $('#password_login').val();
            smartAxiosLogin.post("/login",{ email:email, password:password })
            .then(function (response) {
                if(response.status==200){
                    smartAxios.get("/profile").then(function(response){console.log(response)}).catch(function(error){console.log(error)});
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }); 
        });

I use to store the accessToken into a httpOnly cookie and to pass it through the requests but in this situation where login and profile are on two different subdomains profile call never receives the cookie and so returns 401 (unhautorized).
On the backend cookies are set this way:
res.cookie('accessToken', token, { maxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true, secure: true, Domain: '.mycooldomain.com', Path: '/', SameSite: 'None' });

res.cookie('refreshToken', _token, { maxAge: 86400000, httpOnly: true, secure: true, Domain: '.mycooldomain.com', Path: '/', SameSite: 'None' });

What am I doing wrong? Everything works fine if login and profile are on the same API endpoint.

Does the browser console have anything to say regarding cookies?

The browser doesn’t say anything. The node console on the profile endpoint receives undefined

When you type either of those two URLs above into the browser address bar directly and hit enter - are the cookies getting sent with those requests then? (Trying to determine whether the problem lies in the cookies, or the code that is supposed to send them.)

the cookies are set because if I remove the httponly flag I see them in the browser. So they are correctly received by the browser from login to mydomain. That part works. The part that is not working is from mydomain to profile where the endpoint is giving me undefined

httpOnly only affects whether you can "see them" via JS; your dev tools should be able to show them either way. ("Application" panel in Chrome dev tools, something else in Firefox IIRC.) Did you actually check what I asked you to - what happens, when you request the URL directly?

I decided to get rid of the cookies for access and refresh token implementing the renewal of the refresh token on each use. so this issue went away
